# Using a Html.ActionLink for call an action with a parameter like submit button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a navbar and i want to reach other Action's GET method with Model parameter using Html.ActionLink.

**Controller :**

```
  public ActionResult Balance(Users loggedUser)
    {
        return View(loggedUser);
    }
```

**Html :**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Balance", "Balance", "Home", new {model = Model.user}, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

**Model**

```
   public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Users user { get; set; }
    public Balances balance { get;set; }
    public Sells sell { get; set; }
    public Purchases buy { get; set; }
    public Rates lastRate { get; set; }
    public List<Sells> allSells { get; set; }
    public List<Purchases> allPurchases { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Replace `new {model = Model.user}` with just `Model.user`. But you should not be passing a complex object to the GET method (and it will fail if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections, and you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception). Just pass the ID of the `Users` model.

Comment: When you use `Model.user` as the third parameter(`routeValues`) of this overload, the property values of the `Users` class object will be converted to querystring keys & values and will be added to `Home\Balance`, It will work for lean-flat simple classes. For complex classes, you should rebuild the Users object in your action method,

Comment: i switch Action link like this --- @Html.ActionLink("Add Balance", "Balance", "Home", Model.user.username, new { @class = "navbar-brand" } --- and switched action  ---  public ActionResult Balance(string UserId)  --- but parametre returns null

Comment: It should be `Model.user`. Ex: `@Html.ActionLink("Add Balance", "Balance", "Home", Model.user, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })`

Comment: i send route like (Model.user) and give as (Users loggedUser) and it worked thank you both of you

Answer (score 0):

Sir,

**You can try this:**

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="home" asp-action="home" asp-route-[YOUR-ACTION-PARAMETER-NAME]="[YOUR-ACTION-PARAMETER]">Home</a>
```

**For instance:**

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="home" asp-action="home" asp-route-id="2">Home</a>
```

**or**

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-controller="home" asp-action="home" asp-route-search="sample">Home</a>
```